# LINQ - Group quarterly records

Tags: entity-framework, linq

following is the code to group quarterly records and it's throwing an error -  *OracleException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NCHAR got NCLOB*

```cs
var result = recordsQuery
    .GroupBy(p => (((DateTime)p.PROCESS_STRT_TIME).Month - 1) / 3 + ", " + ((DateTime)p.PROCESS_STRT_TIME).Year)
    .Select(g => new QuarterlyData
    {
        Quarter = g.Key,
        SucccessCount = g.Count(),
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Show your model. It is not clear why you have casted `PROCESS_STRT_TIME` to `DateTime`.

Comment: public Nullable<System.DateTime> PROCESS_STRT_TIME { get; set; }

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query, also corrected Quarter calculation.

```cs
var result = recordsQuery
    .GroupBy(p => new { Year = p.PROCESS_STRT_TIME.Value.Year, Quarter = (p.PROCESS_STRT_TIME.Value.Month - 1)  /  4 + 1 })
    .Select(g => new QuarterlyData
    {
        Quarter = g.Key.Querter.ToString() + ", " + g.Key.Year.ToString(),
        SucccessCount = g.Count(),
    })
    .ToList();
```